# Cross-number of two, three and four-digit numbers

Tags: calculation-puzzle

In this cross-number two-digit numbers are prime numbers, three-digit numbers are square numbers and four-digit numbers are palindromic numbers.

[image: Cross-number]

Comment: The idea comes from here: https://www.zeit.de/2015/08/spiele-logelei-08

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full answer:

> ```
> 441 144
> 841 484
> 411 441
>
> 379 119
> 289 196
> 441 361
> ```

Reasoning for the top right corner:

> The 2-digit prime starting with 4 can be 41, 43 or 47; since no squares end with 3 or 7, it's 41.
>  
>  Next, the right column has to be a square ending with 1 consisting of digits that a square number can end with: 0, 1, 4, 5, 6 and 9. The two candidates are 441 and 961, and 961 doesn't fit because of the top row: no square ending with 9 has 2nd digit which would be a start of a square ending with 4. Thus the right column is 441.
>  
>  Finally, to fill the rest there are squares 144, 324, 484 and 784 ending with 4, of which 324 and 784 can't be used in rows, since either 3 or 7 would have to be the last digit of a square (due to the 4-digit palindromic numbers) or 2 or 8 would have to be the first digit of a square ending with 4. This finishes the square.

For the rest of the digits the logic is pretty much the same, so I'll skip it.